# Import specific column from multiple csv files

Tags: r

I would like to import a specific column from multiple csv files. I have the code below, but this takes the first column, while I have a specific column name ('test') that I would like to import from all the csv files.

```
filenames <- list.files(pattern = '.csv$', full.names = TRUE)

do.call(cbind, lapply(filenames, function(x) {
  setNames(data.frame(read.csv(x)[[1]]), tools::file_path_sans_ext(basename(x)))
})) -> result
```

Should be pretty simple (I hope) but I cannot find the solution... Would be great if you could help me!

Comment: I hope the dupe-link helps, but perhaps a simple alternative: `setNames(x, tools::file_path_sans_ext(basename(x))) |> lapply(function(fn) read.csv(fn)[["test"]]) |> data.frame()`.

Comment: Thanks r2evans, what would 'x' then be?

Comment: Your `filenames`, I think